# USB-to-serial showing garbage but not in Windows 10

Tags: serial-port, putty

I have a [FT232RL](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pc-Basic-Breakout-Board-For-FTDI-FT232RL-USB-to-Serial-IC-For-Hot-Top-Sale/32648158894.html) USB-to-serial adapter which I connect to a microcontroller (esp8266 esp-01). It works fine in Windows 10, if I open a serial communication with putty at `COM3` with baud rate `76800` it shows the expected output. But when I try to do it in Linux I only see garbage.

The steps I followed in ubuntu are the following:

```
$ dmesg | grep FTDI
[    1.918717] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[   10.766450] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[   10.766485] ftdi_sio 1-1.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   10.766889] usb 1-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Also I added my user to `dialout` and `tty` groups but still need `sudo` to open the serial terminal.

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout username
sudo usermod -aG tty username
```

Next I run `sudo putty`, select serial and connect to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and baud rate `76800`. But whenever I restart the microcontroller (when I should get some output in the serial console) I only receive garbage characters.

The output of `lsusb` is the following: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC`

And just in case it's needed:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pcname 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I guess it has something to do with the driver but I have no idea how to fix it.

**UPDATE**: I stopped using Putty and started using `python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyUSB0 76800` and this fixed the problem. Can anyone tell me why? Which is the different configuration that this two programs have for serial communication?

Comment: Did you try 57600 baud instead? 76800 isn't a standard rate.

Comment: At `76800` it is working with the python serial application. The problem seems to be only with putty, maybe something about how they handle DTR and DSR?